# Executing queries in SQLite wrapper (Android persistence library)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-library

I am using [Android persistence library](https://github.com/casidiablo/persistence) as a SQLite wrapper.But i failed to understand how to execute queries in that.Suppose I want to execute below query

`"SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_VIDEO +" where " + KEY_TYPE + "='popular'"+ " order by " + KEY_NOSEEN + " DESC "`

First using this library i am not able to know the column names of the table.Secondly how to exceute `where` clauses using this library.Assuming that variable of object class to be column names i tried to execute following queries-

```
Constraint constraint = new Constraint().orderBy("noOfSeen");
List cached = adapter.findAll(database,constraint);
```

but i get following exception

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: noOfSeen (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY noOfSeen
```

In my application class i added-

```
 DatabaseSpec database = PersistenceConfig.registerSpec(/**db version**/1);
        database.match(Video.class);
```

In adapter i am adding below code to add data to database

```
SqlAdapter adapterpopular = Persistence.getAdapter(mContext);
adapterpopular.store(video);
```

While using database previously without any library i was using following-code

```
String CREATE_VIDEO_TABLE = "create table "
                + TABLE_VIDEO + "(" + KEY_ID + " text not null unique, "
                + KEY_CAPTION + " text not null, "
                + KEY_LOCATION + " text not null, "
                + KEY_NOSHARES + " text not null, "
                + KEY_NOBEENTHERE + " text not null, "
                + KEY_NOMUSTGO + " text not null, "
                + KEY_NOSEEN + " text not null," + KEY_NOCOMMENTS + " text not null, " + KEY_USERNAME + " text not null," + KEY_USERID + " text not null," + KEY_TIMESTAMP + " INTEGER," + KEY_USERHANDLE + " text not null," + KEY_DTS + " text not null," + KEY_TYPE + " text not null," +  KEY_CACHE_TIMESTAMP + " text not null,"+KEY_ISMUSTGO + " text not null," +KEY_ISBEENTHERE + " text not null);";

    public void addVideo(Video videoSql) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_ID, videoSql.getId());
            values.put(KEY_CAPTION, videoSql.getCaption());
            values.put(KEY_LOCATION, videoSql.getLocation());
            values.put(KEY_NOSHARES, videoSql.getNoOfShares());
            values.put(KEY_NOBEENTHERE, videoSql.getNoOfBeenTheres());
            values.put(KEY_NOMUSTGO, videoSql.getNoOfMustGos());
            values.put(KEY_NOCOMMENTS, videoSql.getNoOfComments());
            values.put(KEY_NOSEEN, videoSql.getNoOfSeen());
            values.put(KEY_USERNAME, videoSql.getUserName());
            values.put(KEY_USERID, videoSql.getUserId());
            values.put(KEY_TIMESTAMP, videoSql.getTimestamp());
            values.put(KEY_USERHANDLE, videoSql.getUserHandle());
            values.put(KEY_DTS, videoSql.getDts());
            values.put(KEY_TYPE, videoSql.getType());
            values.put(KEY_CACHE_TIMESTAMP,System.currentTimeMillis());
            values.put(KEY_ISMUSTGO,videoSql.getIsmustGo());
            values.put(KEY_ISBEENTHERE,videoSql.getIsbeenThere());

            try {
                db.replace(TABLE_VIDEO, null, values);
            }catch(Exception e){}

            db.close();
        }
```

Object class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

        public class Video {


            private String no_of_seen;



            public String getNo_of_seen() {
                return no_of_seen;
            }

            @JsonProperty(value = "nSeen")
            public void setNo_of_seen(String no_of_seen) {
                this.no_of_seen = no_of_seen;
            }


        }
```

Comment: Show the table creation code.

Comment: @DerGolem In my application class i just need to add  `DatabaseSpec database = PersistenceConfig.registerSpec(/**db version**/1);
        database.match(Video.class); `  ...please check in the github link..i don't need to write any separate table creation code

Comment: `i am not able to know the column names of the table` And **who** should know the column names of **your** db? It's **obvious** that there is no column named `noOfSeen`, but you are trying to access it anyway.

Comment: @DerGolem Please check the updated question .u'll know what code i am writing and also please check the github link..using this library neither we r giving table name nor column name..it creates itself..

Comment: `it creates itself`, with random column names?!

Comment: @DerGolem If i don't use constraint then my app is able to load complete data ..that means table is created and also data is added to table..i know i am sounding strange but please check the github link..we just need to pass the object class to create table using this library..neither we set table name nor column name

Comment: @DerGolem https://github.com/casidiablo/persistence

Comment: I won't scavenge that **mess** of a code... I use databases very easily without the need of **complicating** my life with that. Anyway, I think you didn't understand how to use that library. It's a **wrapper**. Not a **random** database generator. You must provide at least the table name/s and the column name/s you want to be generated.

Comment: @DerGolem I wrote in questions what all things i did..can u give me an idea by answer how should i proceed in tht?Thanku for ur time..

Comment: No... you should search for `android sqlite crud` and follow a tutorial. This is **not** a tutorial site.

Comment: @DerGolem I just wrote in question what code i was using for adding data to database without any library..just please explain how should i proceed in using this library..i am fresher in android

Comment: `code i was using for adding data to database without any library` Without any library? `I am using Android persistence library`. Are you on acid, or what?

Comment: @DerGolem yeah previously i was not using any library and the code i just added was for that which was working fine..now i want to simplify the code by using this library..

Comment: previously i was not using any library

Comment: `SIMPLIFY`... For me `simplify` means **using no 3rd party library for such a trivial task** as using a database.

Comment: @DerGolem I can't use this statement -'SqlAdapter adapter = Persistence.getAdapter(context);' inside class that extendsSQLiteOpenHelper.and to interact with the database, I must get an implementation of the SqlAdapter interface according to github tutorial

Comment: @DerGolem Okay by looking at tutorial can u just tell me how to insert data to table..i have written in question what code i was previouly using to insert data..Here in tutorial they are insering data to adapter rather than table..i am so confused

Comment: INSERT INTO myTable (Column1_Name, Cloumn2_Name, ...) VALUES (Column1_Value, Column2_Value, ...)

Comment: From the project page: You can also use raw SQL queries: `City bogota = adapter.findFirst(City.class, "name LIKE 'Bogotá'", null);`

Comment: This is not a **raw** query.

Comment: @DerGolem The project page says it's a raw query..

Comment: @DerGolem Thats normal way for inserting data to table..the one which u wrote..by using this library i just need to pass object class but here they are passing to adapter..

Comment: @Everyone , The [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) is for arguments and discussions like this!

Comment: @JonasCz Thank you for being a self-proclamed moderator.

Comment: @JonasCz You have idea how should i proceed in using this wrapper?..i have written in question the code i was using without any wrapper and the code i tried with wrapper..

Comment: From [this](https://github.com/casidiablo/persistence/issues/10) bug report, tables are named like this: `no_of_seen` . You should be able to tell it how to order the result and what to filter by. And, as others have said, this library is not really meant to be used for this kind of thing, you should probably go back to what you had before.

Comment: @DerGolem  Its written in tutorial-Persistence library will automatically create sqlite tables for those classes, which will allow you to insert, query, update and delete data easily.Then how will i be able to know table names and column names?

Comment: The ones you provide. I'm sure there will be a method like `createTable(String tableName)` and one like `addTableColumn(String tableName, String columnName, int columnType)`.

Comment: @DerGolem The thing is, with this library, there is no need to create a column name, as the library does it automatically. See my earlier comment  for how they are named.

Comment: @JonasCz In question i have posted how i am using no_of_seen variable..can u just tell meis this query correct- `Constraint constraint = new Constraint().orderBy("no_of_seen");
List cached = adapter.findAll(database,constraint);`

Comment: You have to try it to see if it's correct...